# python performance bottleneck with lil_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am currently working with sparse matrix in python. I choose to use [lil_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html) for my problem because as explained in the documentation lil_matrix are intended to be used for constructing a sparse matrix. My sparse matrix has dimensions 2500x2500

I have two piece of code inside two loops (which iterate in the matrix elements) which are having different execution time and I want to understand why. The first one is

```
current = lil_matrix_A[i,j]
lil_matrix_A[i, j] = current + 1
lil_matrix_A[j, i] = current + 1
```

Basically just taking every element of the matrix and incrementing its value by one.
And the second one is as below

```
value = lil_matrix_A[i, j]
temp = (value * 10000) / (dictionary[listA[i]] * dictionary[listB[j]])
lil_matrix_A[i, j] = temp
lil_matrix_A[j, i] = temp
```

Basically taking the value, making the calculation of a formula and inserting this new value to the matrix.
The first code is executed for around 0.4 seconds and the second piece of code is executed for around 32 seconds.
I understand that the second one has an extra calculation in the middle, but the time difference, in my opinion, does not make sense. The dictionary and list indexing have O(1) complexity so it is not supposed to be a problem. Is there any suggestion what it is causing this difference in execution time?

Note: The number of elements in list and dictionary is also 2500.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible runnable code? What does your profiler say?

Comment: Are you iterating over every element of the matrix? Not just the currently non-zero ones?  If so, why are you using a sparse matrix?  Why not regular dense one?  (2500,2500) isn't that large for a dense array.

Comment: @hpaulj no I am not. Basically, the first piece code is the construction of the matrix and most of the values will be 0 after it. The logic of the loop of the first code is a bit more complicated so I tried to keep it simple here. But if this helps, it might even have more iterations in the first piece of code than the second piece of code. On the other hand I just changed the second piece of code to skip values equal to 0 from the calculations and I had an improvement from 32 to 9 seconds. However I still think the difference is big.